# Notification icon doesn't show in status bar in lollipop

Tags: android, android-notifications

Here's the code I'm using to show a notification.

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentIntent(contentIntentTwo)
                        .setContentTitle("App name").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(notificationLargeIconBitmap).getNotification();
```

The notification and notification icon show in the pull down notification drawer, but not in the status bar in lollipop.

Here's what it looks like in lollipop :

[image]

This happens only on lollipop.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post links if you found better solution elsewhere. For everyone else, the OP had asked the same question here and got a better reply: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2qjsal/notification_icon_shows_in_white_in_status_bar/

Answer (score 2):

Lollipop changes all non-transparent pixels to white.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorNotifications

Comment: So, all I need to do is `setcolor()`? Could you throw in a little more detail? I just read the documentation, and the only conclusion I can draw from it is to use setcolor

Comment: "The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the main notification icon. You should assume that these icons will be alpha-only. The system draws notification icons in white and action icons in dark gray."

Comment: I just said I read the documentation. My question still stands.

Comment: Your icon is some circle with a picture inside I suppose? Lollipop will mask it with a white overlay. No need to reply btw, I'm done.

Comment: @karaokyo - what should i do to mke the icon visible? it should have a transparent background, but is that enough ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille You can't. Lollipop will mask it with a white overlay. Your icon should have a distinctive shape.

Comment: @karaokyo - am afraid i am not into designing.. but it would be nice if you could guide me a lil more on this so that i could tell the design team.

Comment: There is a notification design doc: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification

Answer (score 0):

for pre-lollipop version, you can still using drawable image. But for lollipop and later, you need transparent background image to be used for notification icon (png preferred). As i know that lollipop version or later will convert any non-transparent color into white color for notification icon for its simplicity and "complexion reduction" idea to reach material design.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_transparant);
    }else{
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
```

https://medium.com/swarm-nyc/complexion-reduction-a-new-trend-in-mobile-design-cef033a0b978#.fblfw0ohi